# Is it possible to use dependency injection with Qt Designer (for .ui files)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, dependency-injection, qt-designer

We are developing in C++ (and Qt) using Visual Studio 2015 and the Qt Designer for our UI (via Form / .ui files).

We now need to share some Common Data between our UI elements (e.g. most recently used paths etc.) and I would like to do this via dependency injection (i.e. providing the UI with a Reference to the common object during construction) instead of e.g. (ab)using the singleton pattern.

Has someone faced (and solved) similar problems, and is there a sensible way to do this?

Update (to elaborate):
For example I have a custom `FooWidget` which I wish to use in my `FooDialog.ui` form file.

```
// My custom Widget
class FooWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    FooWidget(QWidget* parent);
    //...
}

// The FooDialog class (scaffolding created by Qt Designer)
class FooDialog : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    FooDialog(QWidget* parent) : QDialog(parent), ui (new Ui::FooDialog()) {
      ui->setupUp(this);
      //...
  }

  private:
    Ui::FooDialog* ui;
}

// The Ui::FooDialog class autogenerated(!) by Qt Designer
// I cannot (must not) change this code, as it will be regenerated every time
class Ui_FooDialog {
  public:
    FooWidget* widget;

    void setupUi(QWidget *fooDialog) {
        //...
        widget = new FooWidget(fooDialog);
        //...
    }
}
namespace Ui { class ScannerStatus: public Ui_ScannerStatus {}; }
```

I would like to provide the FooWidget with a common data object (e.g. text size and colours shared across all my Ui classes), but I can't do so in the constructor (since the autogenerated Ui_FooDialog treats `FooWidget` as a generic `QWidget`, which only needs/takes a `QWidget* parent` in the constructor - I cannot provide a pointer or reference to my shared `TextColourAndSize` object.

I am aware I could create a second `ui->widget->setupTextColourAndSize(...)` step in `FooDialog` (after the initial `ui->setupUi(this)`) which provides that common data object, but having two `init()` type functions seems like a rather bad code smell (one is bad enough).

Comment: Dependency injection is just using parameters. If you can call a function or construct an object, with an argument, you can do dependency injection.

Comment: dependency injection for UI? This is strange, apparently you are doing something wrong! Anyway it Qt you have signals and slots, so just disconnect some signals slots and connect them to something you want to inject.

Comment: @Clearer I've added an example - changing the constructor is difficult since autogenerated code relies on it, and adding (another) init/setter function also seems not-so-good.

Comment: @MarekR This is something I had not considered - I've updated my question with an example. Can you elaborate on the signals & slots solution?

Comment: @CharonX getter/setter is the opposite of dependency injection.

Comment: @Clearer Really? I thought there is constructor injection (provide dependency in constructor) and [setter injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Setter_injection) (provide dependency via setter method, has IMO several disadvantages compared to constructor-injection, but it is still DI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FooWidget` needs two constructors, and a setter for the dependency:

```
explicit FooWidget(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent), … {
  …
}
FooWidget(Dependency *dep, QObject *parent = nullptr) : FooWidget(parent) {
  setDependency(dep);
}
void setDependency(Dependency *dep) {
  …
}
```

Then you’d set the dependency after the widget is constructed:

```
FooDialog(Dependency *dep, …) … {
  setupUi(this);
  ui->fooWidget->setDependency(dep);
}
```

This could be automated: the parent widget can have a property that holds the pointer to the dependency, and the child widgets can find it automatically:

```
FooDialog(Dependency *, …) : … {
  setProperty("dependency", dep);
  setupUi(this);
}

FooWidget(QWidget *parent) : … {
  auto *dep = parent() ? parent()->property("dependency").value<Dependency*>() : nullptr;
  if (dep) setDependency(dep);
}
```

This will work with no extra effort if `Dependency` derives from `QObject`. Otherwise, you’ll need to have the following in a suitable header file:

```
class Dependency { … };
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Dependency*)
```

**In all circumstances**, you do need to promote the `fooWidget` object to `FooWidget` class within Qt Designer.

Comment: "promoting" widget in Qt Designer is simpler, cleaner and easier to maintain (standard solution).

Comment: @MarekR Promoting the widget doesn’t solve the problem of having custom arguments passed to the constructor. The widget has to be promoted obviously, but that’s only 1/2 of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ok from what I'm seeing you do not need "dependency injection". Question was incorrectly stated.

You can use this custom widget directly from Qt designer.

1. When you create your `FooDialog` place regular widget `QWidget` in place where you need to have a `FooWidget`.
2. Then "promote" regular this widget to `FooWidget` (possibly you have to add some simple information about that type) - (I did that long time ago and do not remember all details).

For detailed instruction just [google: qt promote widget qt designer](https://www.google.com/search?q=qt%20promote%20widget%20qt%20designer), you will find lots of examples how to do it.

Comment: Can you elaborate how I can provide the common data object to my `FooWidget` This way? Promoting it does not seem to give me with way to provide it to the `FooWidget` (e.g. via the constructor), which would only leave me with the option to create a separate (and second) init/setter function (`ui->widget->setupTextColourAndSize(...)`) which is something I'd like to avoid

Comment: `setupTextColourAndSize` indicates quite simple data. You can expose them as properties and then force Qt Designer to set this values (if you want to avoid initialization code). Anyway I don't see a problem with `ui->widget->setupTextColourAndSize(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

These were good solutions, but talking about dependency injections, there is also an option to have some fun with C++. It's not a wise solution at all, of course I know it, but nevertheless...

**foowidget.h**

```
#ifndef FOOWIDGET_H
#define FOOWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class Something
{
public:
    QString getHello() const
    { return "Hello world!"; }
};

/***************************************************/

template<typename T>
class Injector
{
public:
    QString getHello() const
    { return m_dataContainer.getHello(); }

private:
    T m_dataContainer;
};

/***************************************************/

class FooWidget : public QWidget, public Injector<Something>
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FooWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*) override;

};

#endif // FOOWIDGET_H
```

**foowidget.cpp**

```
#include "foowidget.h"

#include <QMessageBox>

FooWidget::FooWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{ }

void FooWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)
{
    QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "Test", getHello());
}
```

**foodialog.h**

```
#ifndef FOODIALOG_H
#define FOODIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

class SomethingElse
{
public:
    QString getHello() const
    { return "OMG! OMG"; }
};


#include "foowidget.h"

namespace Ui {
class FooDialog;
}

class FooDialog : public QDialog, public Injector<SomethingElse>
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FooDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~FooDialog();

protected:
    void showEvent(QShowEvent *) override;

private:
    QScopedPointer<Ui::FooDialog> ui;
};

#endif // FOODIALOG_H
```

**foodialog.cpp**

```
#include "foodialog.h"
#include "ui_foodialog.h"

#include <QMessageBox>

FooDialog::FooDialog(QWidget *parent)
    :  QDialog(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::FooDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

FooDialog::~FooDialog()
{ }

void FooDialog::showEvent(QShowEvent *)
{
    QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "Test", getHello());
}
```

Multiple inheritance + deriving widgets from some small template proxy class works for both custom widgets and those, having UI forms. I've put a FooWidget on a FooDialog (via propagation mechanizm) in the sketch above and got two message boxes.

The idea itself can be implemented better, with smarter template usage, just tried to reduce sample code, anyway it's an unnessesary complication. But technically it works without any additional initializations =)